# Dual monitor help needed [AutoHotkey]

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having trouble getting my script to work on multiple monitors, having searched and found some posts regarding the use of multiple monitors I''m still not sure where I am going wrong and how to fix it.

I am currently using a laptop with an external monitor connected, but I will be sharing this with colleagues who may not have additional monitors. When I run on an application on the main screen (Laptop screen) everything seems to work as expected but when I run it on an application on the additional monitor the coordinates seem to be off.

Please see my code below, I know this may be a mess and could be cleaned up but I'm not quite that knowledgable yet.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

CoordMode, Pixel, Screen    
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

If !FileExist( "Settings.ini" ) {
If ( WinExist("Amazon WorkSpaces") )
{
WinActivate

} Else
{
MsgBox, 48, Auto Clicker, Open AWS!
}
MsgBox Please  close this message and click Start Tracing button
KeyWait, LButton, Down
MouseGetPos, tracingx, tracingy

KeyWait, LButton, Up
MouseGetPos, tracingendx, tracingendy

AHKCommand = %tracingx%, %tracingy%
IniWrite, %tracingx%, Settings.ini, tracing, xcoord
IniWrite, %tracingy%, Settings.ini, tracing, ycoord

MsgBox Please close this message and click Back to consignment list button
KeyWait, LButton, Down
MouseGetPos, backx, backy

KeyWait, LButton, Up
MouseGetPos, backendx, backendy

AHKCommand2 = %backx%, %backy%
IniWrite, %backx%, Settings.ini, back, xcoord
IniWrite, %backy%, Settings.ini, back, ycoord

InputBox, minrefresh, Minimum Refresh, Enter Minimum refresh time in milliseconds (1 min = 60000 milliseconds), , , , , , , , 180000
IniWrite, %minrefresh%, Settings.ini, refresh rates, min

InputBox, maxrefresh, Maximum Refresh, Enter Maximum refresh time in milliseconds (1 min = 60000 milliseconds), , , , , , , , 300000
IniWrite, %maxrefresh%, Settings.ini, refresh rates, max
Return ; This stops the script or returns from the above subroutine.
; ExitApp ; This exits the script entirely
; GoSub, Start ; This jumps to the label start in the script.
; Use non of these to continue the script
}

InputBox, minrefresh, Minimum Refresh, Enter Minimum refresh time in milliseconds (1 min = 60000 milliseconds), , , , , , , , 60000
IniWrite, %minrefresh%, Settings.ini, refresh rates, min

InputBox, maxrefresh, Maximum Refresh, Enter Maximum refresh time in milliseconds (1 min = 60000 milliseconds), , , , , , , , 180000
IniWrite, %maxrefresh%, Settings.ini, refresh rates, max

^+z::  ; Control+Shift+Z hotkey.


IniRead, tracingx, Settings.ini, tracing, xcoord
IniRead, tracingy, Settings.ini, tracing, ycoord
IniRead, backx, Settings.ini, back, xcoord
IniRead, backy, Settings.ini, back, ycoord
AHKCommand = %tracingx%, %tracingy%
AHKCommand2 = %backx%, %backy%
Random, rand, %minrefresh%, %maxrefresh%


Loop {
If ( WinExist("Amazon WorkSpaces") )
{
WinActivate
PixelGetColor, color, %tracingx%, %tracingy%
If (color = 0xEFEFEF) {
Click %AHKCommand%
Sleep, 2000
PixelGetColor, color, %backx%, %backy%
If (color = 0xF5F5F5) {
Click %AHKCommand2%
Sleep, 2000

} Else 
{
MsgBox, , Auto Clicker, You have a call!
}

} Else 
{
MsgBox, 48, Auto Clicker, Check Settings!]
}
} Else
{
MsgBox, 48, Auto Clicker, Open AWS!
}
Sleep, %rand%
}
```

What I hope to happen is on starting the script it checks for settings and if it doesn't find them it will ask you for the information. once this check is done it will click a set location from the data you provided at an interval set by yourself and check it matches the specific colour (button present/not present) then displays errors or messages as required. Pretty simple so far?

The problem comes when I have the application on the additional monitor. At first, I thought nothing was happening, but with a msgbox here and there I can now see that the coordinates I selected during setup are correct but when the script is running the coordinates seem to be off by a varying amount (Currently between 105 & 120px on the x-axis and between 145 & 147px on the y-axis.

Is this going to work, or should I give up and get everyone using it on the main laptop screen?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to "click" into an AWS desktop from a local PC to keep the AWS alive (so it doesn't lock-screen or disconnect automatically after a period of time)? Are you running AWS in full-screen mode? Check the DPI setting (or other monitor setting) may be different on the AWS than the local PC.

Comment: Basically yes. In AWS I have a chrome window open where I need to click a button followed by another button on the next page in a loop. I actually didn't think about it going to lock screen. I found full screen didn't work to an even worse extent but my it seems to be fine in a maximised window but only on the main laptop screen. Does DPI matter? I didn't know this.  Maybe this is the/a cause

Comment: OK is the ahk script running on the AWS machine or on the local PC clicking into an AWS window?  The first should be doable and you can make adjustments by simply looking at the internal monitor variables with `SysGet` to retrieve screen resolution, multi-monitor info, dimensions of system objects, and other system properties and which you can check out here https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SysGet.htm

Comment: No, unfortunately we can't upload anything directly to AWS so it's being run on a local pc clicking into AWS

Comment: Then your best bet is to use `ImageSearch` or `PixelSearch` then, but I have not had much success.

Comment: I do currently use PixelGetColor which works but again only properly on my main screen. When on the external monitor everything appears to work until it involves coordinates so MouseMove, Click etc all fail even though the coordinates used are correct. I.E the coordinates are saved to file, these match what window spy says and match where you click but when moving it doesn't actually go to that point but some place approx 100px away on both axis

Comment: I didn't bother with studying the code, but based off these comments I can offer one guess. If you say it's not clicking the coordinates you're specifying, but somewhere near there, maybe it's if you move the cursor super fast and click right away. Maybe the remote desktop client you use processes your cursor location only every so often and if you move your cursor a lot and fast it cant keep up. Maybe try moving the cursor to the desired location first, and then clicking after a short delay.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've checked this removing the loop I had and changed to a simple mouse move and click and can see its moving the cursor to the same but incorrect position. I can confirm this by using windowspy and compare it to the stored settings while running the script. It just doesn't seem to go to where you tell it. I also feel that the remote desktop client issue couldn't be a cause as it would do the same when using my main screen. It's really got me thinking.